# Meaning of pullback in algebraic topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

Here's a confusion on meaning of a sentence in *A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology*:

Let $f$: $A\to B$ be a map ( where A is connected and locally path connected ) and D is a component of the pullback of f along p, then $p:$ $D\to A$ is a cover.

Question: what does it mean by pullback of a function along another function? ( I understood construction of pullback square in category theory )

Comment: Can you explain what $p$ is?

Comment: Sometimes by pullback they mean precomposition - the obvious map $[A,B] \to [D,B]$, if you have a map $D \to A$.

Comment: There May refers to the pullback of a cover $p:E\rightarrow B$, which is a special case of the pullback of fiber bundles which you can see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_bundle (which is also a special case of the categorical construction).

Comment: If you understand the categorical picture, then you understand the picture